# Vertex - OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I am new to OpenGL and I am developing an iPhone application that uses OpenGl to render shapes (squares, polygones, etc.) and images.
I have been reading that we specify coordinates for the vertices (x, y and z), their color (r,b,g and a) and finally, the corresponding texture coordinates.

In my case, some of the vertices only have position and color coordinates (shape vertices), meanwhile the others have position and texture coordinates (image vertices).

How can I work with an array of vertices that have position and color attributes, and another array that have position and texture attributes? And what should I put in the shaders?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried and what is your problem? As you wrote it would seem you have 2 arrays of vertices so for the first one draw it using position and colour while for the other one use the position and texture.

Comment: Exactly, my problem is that I don't know how to draw two different arrays that have different attributes, and how to manage the shaders. What I mean is that what should I put in the shaders? And how should I draw two arrays that have different types of vertices?